# Pass variable from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller, I can get the organization name but when I pass it to the view
there's an error. It said invalid argument supplied for foreach( ):

[image: Error Message].

This is my codes.

**Controller**

```
public function index()

{
  $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  $data['title'] = "User";
  $getID['orgID'] = $this->userModel->getOrganizationID($user_id); // used my session user_id to 
    foreach ($getID['orgID'] as $orgID) 
  {
    $org_id = $orgID->org_id;

    $getName['myOrganization'] = $this->userModel->myOrganization($org_id);

    foreach($getName['myOrganization'] as $orgName)
    {
     $name = $orgName->org_name;
     $data['name'] = $name;
    }
  }
  $this->load->view('xxxx/xxxx/xxxx',$data);
```

**Model**

```
public function getOrganizationID($user_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('org_id');
        $this->db->from('organization_members');
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        return $query->result();

    }
    public function myOrganization($org_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('org_name');
        $this->db->from('tblorganization');
        $this->db->where('org_id', $org_id);
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        return $query->result();

    }
```

**[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9dBH.png)**

First array is my result of $getID['orgID'] = $this->userModel->getOrganizationID($user_id); which I used my user_id session to get all the org_id of the user then

Second array is my result of $getName['myOrganization'] = $this->userModel->myOrganization($org_id); which I used my org_id(from my previous method) to get all the org_name of the user.

Comment: What is the return value of `$this->userModel->myOrganization($org_id)`?

Comment: And also, what is the value of the `$ord_id` parameter you pass in?

Comment: The $org_id i pass in to my $this->userModel->myOrganization($org_id); is int then the return value of $this->userModel->myOrganization($org_id); is array of string, check my output,.

Answer (score 0):

Is there going to be more then one result? Because if its only one result then you can use $query->row(); and eliminate the foreach completely.

Always check to make sure your database method worked AND that you actually got a returned value whenever you are making any database call. So i'll let you add the if condition in the database method but in short it should return FALSE if nothing came back. So thats the database method heres one way of doing it in your controller. Note this:  $getID['orgID'] is very awkward. You are getting results back from the members table so call it members.

```
// check for the negative first - if no members came back 
if( ! $members = $this->userModel->getOrganizationID($user_id) ) 
{
    // if no results back leave this method 
    // pass the user id so you can echo it out in the error page 
    $this->showNoResultsFor($user_id) ; 
} 
else{

    foreach ($members as $member) 
  {

    $org_id = $member->org_id;

     // etc etc etc
```

Comment: ok... would still recommend you do error checking similar to above. And in your code you are returning an object from your model method. If you want an array then change it to $query->result_array();

Comment: i changed my model into $query->result_array(); i still have error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: there are a lot of different things that could be wrong. thats why i'm suggesting error checking in your model method and in your controller. that helps to locate where the error is. but first - work through the tutorial in the manual to get a better understanding of codeigniter basics. don't just read it - actually do the code and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a codeigniter expert but looking at your code, I am wondering why you are setting:

```
$getID['orgID'] = $this->userModel->getOrganizationID($user_id);
```

First, you are setting an array `$getID['orgID']` rather than just using something like `$memberships = ...`; I'm not sure why you are casting an array.

Secondly, you seem to be referencing a model class without instantiating it:

```
$this->userModel->getOrganizationID($user_id);
```

Perhaps codeigniter does some magic? `$this` refers to **this** instance and from the code you show, your model is likely in a separate class/file so I am unclear how `$this->userModel` is referenced in your method, unless you are instantiating it in your Controller's constructor?

From what I see it looks like you are getting the error because you are not supplying a valid object/array to your foreach. Perhaps start by testing you are actually getting a valid return from `$this->userModel->getOrganizationID($user_id)`.

Comment: I declared userModel in my constructor and i already checked myOrganization and getOrganizationID method. It have an result..Do you want to see my output?